# Git subtree that is dependent on the parent directory, or fork that only pushes some subfolders upstream

Tags: git, github, git-subtree

What I want to do in my project is fork an existing "framework" repository i've developed, and create a subfolder within the forked repo to store project-specific files (think "engine" and "game").  I want to retain the ability to make changes to the framework while working on this project, within a branch so as not to automatically affect the master branch should the fork be merged in, but I don't want to push the project subfolder (or any other project-related subfolders, should I want to add any) to the main framework repo on github.  I DO want all the subfolders including any project-specific subfolders to be pushed to the project repo, keeping everything nicely packaged.  Is there a way to do this without forcing the framework into a subfolder?

Answer (score 1):

Branches, branches everywhere!

Work on your subfolder in your private branch, let's name it 'private'. Fork off a branch from master to work on framework, named 'my-frm'. Merge my-frm to both master (and make pull requests with it) and also merge it to your private branch.

Comment: Thanks so much for answering, but just to see if I got it ...

1. Fork "main" and clone it ... let's call the fork "framework-game"

2. In framework-game, make a branch called game and a branch called framework.

3. When I make changes to the framework files, commit them to the framework branch only (stash / commit any parallel game changes before checking out framework) .

4. Merge the changes back into the game branch.

5. PR framework-game to "main" 

Is it a good idea to merge to master before making PRs?

Stupid SO... markdown isn't working in this comment :/

Comment: Where do you merge is up to you. It only depends on where (in what branches) you need the changes. If you need them in two or three branches — it's perfectly ok to merge 2 or 3 times.

PS. Comments are for quick notes so they deliberately support only very limited subset of markdown.

Comment: So, I just learned a ton about Git thanks to you.  For instance I didn't realize you could have a private branch in the same repo and make it push to a different remote, or, different local repos with a subset of branches from the same or different origins (which will allow the game project to have several related branches without overcrowding the main one)

Comment: This approach turned out to be not ideal; I often make changes to the framework in project so that they can be tested in-situ, and then I have to "tease apart" things through either stashing, switching branches, applying the stash and discarding any non-framework changes, committing, and then merging this way and that (to master, to project, etc) OR i just make all commits on the project and cherrypick them onto the framework, but this is error prone and clutters the history.  

For this reason I am considering adopting submodules since Gitkraken supports them.  Any insights?